# How to remove Cinnamon etc. and leave just Ubuntu?

Tags: cinnamon

I have Cinnamon and many more. How can I remove them and leave just Ubuntu?

Comment: How did you install those desktop environments? Please include that in your question. Then we can provide answers how to undo that. And perhaps you mean "Unity" instead of Ubuntu in this context.

Comment: @gertvdijk Via command line, I didn't really remember the exact command, but it was like 1-2 lines only.

Comment: Can you add `dpkg -l | grep cinnamon`?

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/a/360878/19110

Comment: This question also might have some advice for you: http://askubuntu.com/q/361392/236

Answer (score 10):

Genrally I would do (replace `cinnamon` with the other desktop enviroments, e.g. kde4):

```
sudo apt-get remove cinnamon
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Go to https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt-get.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto for more info.

Comment: Also add `sudo apt remove --autoremove cinnamon-*`

Answer (score 0):

## First, check what is going to be removed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep .cinnamon.
```

## If you are ok with it, run this command

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge cinnamon*
```

## Command explanation

```
# dpkg -l       lists all installed packages
# grep .cinnamon.   filters, so that only packages with keyword cinnamon within their names, listed
# purge         removes mentioned package
# autoremove    tries to remove dependency packages
```

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled cinnamon and when I restarted I had a computer, home & trash icon on my desktop.  what I did was I went into synaptic.  Make sure that you hit the all button to show  ALL of the residual and installed programs.  Search for cinnamon in the search bar. the installed programs will be green.  what you do is you right click and scroll to the bottom where it says complete removal. After checking all the green boxes hit the apply button. It may take some time but don't worry its working.  After that is done you will go to the bottom left and hit the status button and then above that scroll down to residual and click it.  you will then mark all of those for complete removal.  hit apply.  At this point you will have to restart your computer.  all of the residual information of cinnamon will be completely off and you will have your original desktop back.