# Does cinnamon 2.0 really break your 13.10 desktop?

Tags: 13.10, cinnamon

I was reading an article that warns not to use cinnamon 2.0 on ubuntu 13.10 or it will break. Is this true? This is the article.

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Cinnamon-2-0-Corrupts-Unity-on-Ubuntu-13-10-390736.shtml

Comment: see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360772/unity-isnt-starting-on-13-10

Comment: It seems the issue is solved and Cinnamon 2.0 doesn't break Unity anymore: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/cinnamon-20-no-longer-breaks-unity-in.html

Answer (score 6):

> **Update 7. december 2013: This happened just at the release of 13.10, but it is reported that this shouldn't cause issues any more.**

Yes, this is true, it happened to me as well. I couldn't login to the Unity session after upgrading to 13.10 and had to uninstall Cinnamon to get it working. It seems like this is the solution for everyone having a similar problem.

My knowledge is limited and I can't tell you the exact reason why this is happening :) But your link already gives a possible reason for the problem - a common gnome package.

Comment: So if you removed unity, then you could cinnamon?

Comment: I think so,it was the same problem under 13.04

Comment: Yes my Unity broke after installing Cinnamon 2.0. But I prefer Cinnamon over Unity, so that's okay for me.

Comment: This is not true anymore...

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, Cinnamon 2.0 still uses some parts of Gnome 3 that are different from the ones that Unity expects so you can only have one or the other working until Cinnamon totally removes all Gnome references from it. I prefer Cinnamon over Unity by far so installed Xbuntu to be sure I don't start with rogue Gnome parts installed and put Cinnamon on it as my desktop to try it out.
On a fresh install I just did, the files I think are in conflict are:

```
gnome-session-common 3.9.90
gnome-session 3.9.90
g-system-monitor 3.8.2
g-terminal-data 3.6.1
g-terminal 3.6.1
gnome-session-fallback 3.6.2
```

I am pretty sure Unity needs other versions to run. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

While Cinnamon team is working to fix the issue, here is the quick way to fix it. Open a terminal and use the following command:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/share/upstart/sessions/cinnamon-se*
```

This will remove the Cinnamon files from the upstart session. The trick is suggested by Michael Webster of Cinnamon dev team.

Answer (score 1):

The problem only occures with Cinnamon 2.0 from an additional repository. I recommend to uninstall Cinnamon by simply using `sudo apt-get remove .*cinnamon.*` and `sudo apt-get remove .*nemo.*`

The repository probably was disabled automatically during Ubuntu upgrade, but it might be good to check this or remove it: `http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable/ubuntu`

Now reinstall Cinnamon and Nemo simply trough the Ubuntu repositories. You can use `apt-get`, Synaptic or even the Software Center.

With Ubuntu 13.10 Cinnamon and Nemo are easy to choose for all Ubuntu users! :) Though instead of version 2.0 you will get 1.8.4 (as of today)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the situation seems to be slightly better than "you have to remove Cinnamon", at least with its more recent releases. I had the same issue because of Nemo which I prefer over standard Ubuntu file manager. So I uninstalled Cinnamon completely (via Synaptic, but the method does not matter really), logged into Unity which was working, and then *installed Cinnamon again*.

After this procedure, Unity (currently 7.1.2 version) is working quite normally as far as I can tell alongside cinnamon-2.0.12 and nemo-2.0.6 (at this moment). The only glitch is that it is not able to display any desktop background, be it plain colour or a photo.