# Gnome extensions don't work! I've tried everything!

Tags: unity, gnome, login-screen, browser, plugins

When I go to https://extensions.gnome.org/, and try to install an extension, it clicks on, but nothing happens to my shell. Then, when I reload the page, the slider has turned off. Here are the things I have tried:

I tried Chrome, Firefox, and Opera

adding http://extensions.gnome.org to my allow plugin list in google chrome and made sure gnome-intigration is enabled

I made a new firefox profile and tried installing it

I reset my gnome shell settings ([How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)) - this link actually broke my system, as now I can't log in to any desktop environment, the only way I can get to Unity, is by logging in to another desktop environment like cinnimon (which doesn't work) , then immediately logging into unity. Whenever I try to just log into unity or pretty much any other desktop environment, it logs in, but then seems to crash, and log out. Sometimes I even get quick glances of the Unity bar before it crashes

I tried-re installing gnome

None of these methods worked!! Thank you in advance!!

EDIT:

GNOME Shell 3.4.1

Ubuntu 12.04

Chrome Version: 30.0.1599.114

Comment: have you checked http://askubuntu.com/questions/361392/does-cinnamon-2-0-really-break-your-13-10-desktop ?

Comment: Please provide details about the versions of Ubuntu and GNOME you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I'm behind a proxy. In my case I had to configure the global network proxy under `Settings`, `Network`, `Network Proxy`.